# Is polymorphism sometimes slower than if/elses?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Particularly in java. The polymorphically refactored code is running slower. Is it possible that polymorphism could be the culprit or perhaps there is a confounding performance drain unrelated to polymorphism.

Comment: Even if it is, any sane person should be willing to pay the performance price whenever polymorphism is the superior solution (i.e. quite often).

Answer (score 8):

Write some benchmarking code to do each of them, and measure their performance.

Anything else is guesswork.

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically it could be because JVM has to load class and create its instance before running the code. If/else structure does not require loading additional classes. But I have never seen real use cases when performance improvement should be done by loosing the design quality.

Comment: How your answer concerns polymorphism?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, polymorphism could be slower than if/else. That would depend on the internals of your platform (Java).

But speed is not the reason to use polymorphism. Polymorphism is used to make your solution easier to read and understand - more maintainable.

If speed is an important concern, it is acceptable to sacrifice that maintainability and not use polymorphism.

EDIT:

As pointed out in a number of comments and other answers - don't make the decision blindly. Measure performance impact first.

Comment: Before you sacrifice structural clarity for performance be sure that it is in fact the biggest inefficiency remaining.  Most systems can get much more performance improvement out of algorithmic optimization than changing polymorphic classes into a bunch of switch statements.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism is slower, and there are several reasons (e.g. dynamic method lookup). As mentioned in the answers above, it is not a reason to use if/else instead of polymorphism. `final` specifier sometimes helps to speed-up the code by optimizing it.